# In what order does implode() join element values

Tags: php, implode

I'm wondering in what order does implode() join element values. I was hoping that it did it on the basis of the key values but it doesn't seem to do that. Is there some other function that does allow you to do that?

So that if I have:

```
$test_arr = array(2 => 'there', 1 => 'Hi ', 3 => '!');
```

and do

```
$stringy = implode($test_arr);
```

the variable $stringy will contain the string: 'Hi there!'?

When I tried it with implode I got 'thereHi !', so I'm guessing the array some how keeps track of in what order I defined the elements and then implode uses that information to join?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`implode()` just joins the items as they are defined in the array.

To do what you want to do you need to sort if first:

```
$test_arr = array(2 => 'there', 1 => 'Hi ', 3 => '!');
ksort($test_arr, SORT_NUMERIC);

$stringy = implode($test_arr);
```